# php migration/ insert from database on one server to other server using pdo

Tags: php, pdo, php-5.6

I have created connections to databases on two servers named $DBH and $DBH1-

```
$DBH = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbserver;dbname=$database", "$dbuser", "$dbpassword");

$DBH1 = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbserver1;dbname=$database1", "$dbuser1", "$dbpassword1");
```

I need to select data(100000 rows) from $DBH and insert it into $DBH1.
[The source table is huge 100 million rows / 13 GB]
Is there a simpler way than looping through 100000 rows and inserting?

Comment: are the field names and so on completly the same or do you need to change data?

Comment: field names are completely same.

Comment: db names are also same, you can call it a partial migration.

Comment: and you want to do that just one time now to change database or this should be none frequently?

Comment: every 10 minutes in small chunks for a week..

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to just backup the table on DB1 and restore it to DB2? Would be finished in a few minutes

Comment: @RiggsFolly The table is huge 100 million rows / 13 GB.

Comment: Do you want to move the whole table or just pieces of it?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Just pieces..

Comment: @RiggsFolly Let me know if there is a solution

Comment: @ChristopherSupertramp Let me know if there is a solution

Comment: Another option, read through the DB with data in, generate output into a `.sql` file in the format that you can run on DB2 as just a list of inserts and use mysql.exe to run the inserts

Comment: ok @RiggsFolly, thanks for the solution, will try it.